# NoFlo components with different runtimes in a single graph

Tags: runtime, noflo

NoFlo can run with different runtimes.

Is it possible to connect components that run with different runtimes? That is to say, execute scripts written in different languages but connected in a single graph.

I would like to know if it is possible to do the same as what shell scripts can do, lauching the execution of scripts written in different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something currently being worked on. You may want to watch the progress with [RemoteSubGraph](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-runtime/blob/master/src/RemoteSubGraph.coffee) in the [noflo-runtime](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-runtime) library.

Comment: Perfect, it will allow an almost total flexibility in graph development. Thank you!

Comment: Configuration example [in the Ingress Table project](https://github.com/c-base/ingress-table/blob/master/package.json#L61)